# Angular Removes timezone of the date in Http Request

Tags: angular

This is a simple form with Http request.

```
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="save()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Metting Date :</label>
    <kendo-datepicker class="form-control" name="meetingDate"
      [(ngModel)]="this.model.meetingDate"></kendo-datepicker>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the component

```
save() {
  // if we print the date it is :
  // Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time) 
  console.log(this.model) 

  this.httpClient.post("http://xxx/meeting", Object.assign({}, this.model), this.httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
  })
}
```

but if we inspect the network tab of the browser we will see the timezone is removed, as below. why?

```
"2019-12-31T20:30:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :-

```
this.httpClient.post("http://xxx/meeting", Object.assign({}, this.model), this.httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
  })
```

to

```
const meetingDate = this.model.meetingDate.toString();   
const req = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));
req.meetingDate = meetingDate;
this.httpClient.post("http://xxx/meeting",  req, this.httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks , if I convert it to string my request payload will be like : [object Object] , why ?

Comment: Again , my request payload will be like : [object Object], If you try the example above you will notice

Comment: No it will not be, try to send it. Api will receive the date. Can you tell what is your this.model?

Comment: You need to apply toString only to the property having date.

Comment: @alidavoodi i have updated my answer to incorporate that, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is not something related to Angular, but its just how the JSON.stringify method works

Comment: Thanks, In your opinion what should I do?

Comment: I think that you should just allow more parameters into your API, for example you could add the timezone specific param and pass it by retrieving from the Date object

Comment: I don't think that's logical to save timezone in specific prop

Comment: I dont want you to save in another prop, pass it to the API, then you can store it however you want

Comment: @alidavoodi if you're gonna be working with timezones a lot, do yourself a favor and use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). I've tried before working with plain Date objects because I didn't want to use a 3rd party library, but I pulled my hair out way too many times...